# How can I concatenate this result set?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have read all the related questions but could not get this simple thing working. I'd like to concatenate the results of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ord.uid AS u
  FROM  `uc_order_products` ord_prod,  `uc_orders` ord,  `uc_roles_expirations` re
WHERE ord.order_id = ord_prod.order_id
  AND ord_prod.title LIKE  '2012. évi%'
  AND ord.uid NOT 
IN (SELECT uid FROM uc_roles_expirations re)
```

It looks like this:

```
U
----
1234
1235
...
```

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ord.uid AS u
  FROM  `uc_order_products` ord_prod,  `uc_orders` ord,  `uc_roles_expirations` re
WHERE ord.order_id = ord_prod.order_id
  AND ord_prod.title LIKE  '2012. évi%'
  AND ord.uid NOT 
IN (SELECT uid FROM uc_roles_expirations re) SEPARATOR ',')
```

..and did not work. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only the columnName should be in the `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ord.uid SEPARATOR ',')AS u
FROM  `uc_order_products` ord_prod,  
        `uc_orders` ord,  
        `uc_roles_expirations` re
WHERE ord.order_id = ord_prod.order_id
  AND ord_prod.title LIKE  '2012. évi%'
  AND ord.uid NOT 
IN (SELECT uid FROM uc_roles_expirations re)
```

*PS: As side note, this uqery will produce a cartesian result due to lacking of join condition on this table `uc_roles_expirations`. What is the relationship of the table on the other table?*

*I'm not sure*, but I think you want the result of this query,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ord.uid SEPARATOR ',')AS u
FROM  `uc_order_products` ord_prod
       INNER JOIN `uc_orders` ord
          ON ord.order_id = ord_prod.order_id
WHERE ord_prod.title LIKE  '2012. évi%' AND 
      ord.uid NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM uc_roles_expirations)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(u ORDER BY u)
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT ord.uid AS u
  FROM  `uc_order_products` ord_prod,  `uc_orders` ord,  `uc_roles_expirations` re
WHERE ord.order_id = ord_prod.order_id
  AND ord_prod.title LIKE  '2012. évi%'
  AND ord.uid NOT 
IN (SELECT uid FROM uc_roles_expirations re)
) t
```